# Primefaces GMap Marker with Label

Tags: google-maps, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a gmap which I setup in my .xhtml and add markers to it in my action :

```
<p:gmap id="topologyMap" fitBounds="true" type="MAP"
                            mapTypeControl="false" draggable="true" disableDoubleClickZoom="true"
                            navigationControl="false" streetView="false"
                            style="width:100%;height:500px"
                            model="#{Action.simpleModel}" disableDefaultUI="true">
```

In my Action I have

```
MapModel simpleModel = new DefaultMapModel();;
Marker newMarker = new Marker(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
newMarker.setIcon("resources/media/marker-blue-dot.png");
simpleModel.addOverlay(newMarker);
```

I cant figure out how to add a label to my marker. By label I mean I want to show some text underneath my marker, example: name of the city underneath a marker. I am using primefaces 6.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must use some Javascript for this

```
  <script>

        google.maps.Marker.prototype.setLabel = function (label) {
            this.label = new MarkerLabel({
                map: this.map,
                marker: this,
                text: label
            });
            this.label.bindTo('position', this, 'position');
        };

        var MarkerLabel = function (options) {
            this.setValues(options);
            this.span = document.createElement('span');
            this.span.className = 'map-marker-label';
        };

        MarkerLabel.prototype = $.extend(new google.maps.OverlayView(), {
            onAdd: function () {
                this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.span);
                var self = this;
                this.listeners = [
                    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed', function () {
                        self.draw();
                    })
                ];
            },
            draw: function () {
                var text = String(this.get('text'));
                var position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
                this.span.innerHTML = text;
                this.span.style.left = position.x + 'px';
                this.span.style.top = position.y + 'px';
            }
        });

        //This is the base function
        function initialize() {

            //Take the map from Primefaces Gmap
            var gmap = PF('geoMapV').getMap();

            //Take All Markers in from the map
            var myMarkers = gmap.markers;

            //Add Label to the marker
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; myMarkers.length > i; i++) {
                myMarkers[i].setLabel("Marker Label!!");
            }

        }

    </script>
```

And then add some style to show the marker in the map

```
<style>
        .map-marker-label {
            position: absolute;
            color: red;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            /* Use margin to position the text */
            /* top, left position is the place of marker position */
            margin-top: -30px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    </style>
```

And I call  the `initialize()` from the ManageBean

```
     //Call Javascript from the labels  markers
     RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("initialize()");
```

**The result**

[image: The result]

Answer (score -1):

There is a constructor of Marker with a title string:

```
public Marker(LatLng latlng, String title)
```

Comment: @joshuadetwiler: That is a remarkable comment you make since for me it made it possible to have a marker with label/title. PF showcase even uses it https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/addMarkers.xhtml